# How to highlight nested elements inside SVG and change their color or highlight them in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, touchableopacity, react-native-svg

We have a map of a mall which is an image(SVG, or PNG), I'm asked to do the following:

there is an input above the Map where user can look for a store by name, when a store is chosen it should be selected in the Map like highlighted or something to show his position in the mall, the second task is :

the user can press on any store to select it we should highlight the store and open a bottomsheet.

my question is:

which solution could be used to accomplish this behavior, if an SVG is used i know that there are difficulties using TouchableOpacities inside and SVG, how can we highlight the selected store inside the card ? which data should i receive from backend ? i'm thinking of using an array where the first element in the array would be the first right top store in the map in our case the array should be somthing like this :

[A-FITNESS , DECATLON, DNS , KARI ]

i'm thinking of using an array where the first element in the array would be the first right top store in the map in our case the array should be somthing like this :

[A-FITNESS , DECATLON, DNS , KARI ]

but i don't know how to click nested elements inside an SVG and how to change the color or highlight a part of the SVG

Comment: Every `path` inside your SVG object there should get some `id="storeName"` or so by which you can find it like that. Once found you can play around with the `fill`

Comment: You'll need to use `https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg` for that.  The readme also describes how to convert your SVG code to react-native-svg applicable code. Most (if not all) elements have `onPress()` there.

Comment: I apologize for my confusion, SVG tags have an onPress method and we can use it to handle clicks. However I used that in every path I have inside my SVG, but how should I know which path is for which store ? And sometimes other elements are changing colors also. Should I ask designer to put every store in a path ? Can he do that ?

Comment: yes, you would need every store in a different path an assign it an `id`. Like that you can keep track which path is which store. If more elements should light up you'll just need an array of those "path id's" to keep track of and iterate over them.